# How does vue watch sublist change or v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to watch a list that has sub list and some `<input>` can change the sublist well.

```js
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="sub in list">
        <div v-for="(v,idx) in sub">
            <input v-model="sub[idx]"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        list: [['one','two']]    
    },
    watch: {
        list: funtion(){
            console.log('change')
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

**when I modify the input,watcher doesn't work**

Comment: what do you mean by modify the input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a [deep watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) in order to watch nested changes and trigger the watch:

```js
watch: {
   list: {
     handler() {
         console.log('change')
     },
     deep: true
   }
}
```

## Interesting:

If the nested data is any of the following, the watch will **not** fire without a `deep` watch:

- array of objects  (by far the most common)
- object of objects
- object of arrays

But if the nested data is an array of arrays, as in your code, Vue *can* detect it.  It would have worked with the typo fixed (as addressed in @BorisK's  answer below).

This is somewhat unexpected because we think of Vue as unable to detect deep changes without a `deep` watch, but it can with an array of arrays, and not just in the template.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/a5962eqh)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `funtion` with `function` (you forgot a `c`)

Click "run code snippet" below to see it in action

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [
      ['one', 'two']
    ]
  },
  watch: {
    list: function() {
      console.log('change');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div v-for="sub in list">
    <div v-for="(v,idx) in sub">
      <input v-model="sub[idx]" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 from me, apparently Vue can deep watch an array of arrays without `deep`.  Check my answer for some interesting factoids